# Recursively search for a value in global variables and its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, global-variables

Let's say that I want to search for a value, like `'StackOverflow'`, in all declared variables in `window`.
I can do it with this code:

```
function globalSearch(obj, value) {
    for(var p in obj)
        if(obj[p] == value)
            return(p);
}
globalSearch(window, 'StackOverflow');
```

This code will return the name of a variable that have this value (or returns nothing).
So, if I have declared a variable with value `'StackOverflow'`, it will successfully find it.

My problem is that I want to go deeper and search thru `window`'s objects (and its own nested objects) too, to achieve a result like this:

```
var x = 'StackOverflow'                     // returns 'x'
var y = { a : 'StackOverflow' }             // returns 'y.a'
var z = { a : { b: 'StackOverflow' } }      // returns 'z.a.b'
```

I'm having problems with inherited methods of Objects. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What so you mean by problems with inherited methods?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Deep search but without the recursive function calls**

Functional recursion has internal stack limits and wastes memory.

**Additional features added**

Recursive object protection in the form of a searched array; It doesn't use up too much memory of course as the objects are only stored as references.

Return true if the the object itself matches the value. Otherwise it would return '' which would match to false.

Arrays use angle-bracket notation.

**The code**

```
function globalSearch(startObject, value) {
    var stack = [[startObject,'']];
    var searched = [];
    var found = false;

    var isArray = function(test) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call( test ) === '[object Array]';
    }

    while(stack.length) {
        var fromStack = stack.pop();
        var obj = fromStack[0];
        var address = fromStack[1];

        if( typeof obj == typeof value && obj == value) {
            var found = address;
            break;
        }else if(typeof obj == "object" && searched.indexOf(obj) == -1){
           if ( isArray(obj) ) {
              var prefix = '[';
              var postfix = ']';
           }else {
              var prefix = '.';
              var postfix = '';
           }
           for( i in obj ) {
              stack.push( [ obj[i], address + prefix + i + postfix ] );
           }
           searched.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return found == '' ? true : found;
}
```

**Problems**

Without passing the initial variable name into the function, we can't return the fully qualified variable name from the beginning. I can't think of a solution and I would be surprised if there was one.

Variable names with spaces are valid as the key to an object, as are other invalid variable names,  it just means that the value must be addressed using angle-brackets. There are a couple of solutions I can think of. Regex check each variable name to make sure it's valid and use angle-brackets notation if it is not. The overriding problem with this is that the reg-ex is a page long. Alternatively, we could only use angle-brackets but this isn't really true to the OPs original question.

The indexOf call on the array 'searched' might be a bit heavy on very large objects but I can't yet think of an alternative.

**Improvements**

Apart from cleaning up the code a little, it would also be nice if the function returned an array of matches. This also raises another issue in that the returned array would not contain references to recursive objects. Maybe the function could accept a result format configuration parameter.

Comment: Running this on virtually any page in the firebug console, I get "The operation is insecure." I'm messing around with some error-catching schemes, but I'm not sure I'll find anything good enough to add here. Maybe someone else can make an improvement that gets around this?

Comment: Doing it with window: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at globalSearch (<anonymous>:27:32)

Comment: Here's a gist with an improved version of your code: https://gist.github.com/stracker-phil/e5b3bbd5d5eb4ffb2acdcda90d8bd04f
The function searches all occurrences and stores them in an array, also it additionally allows searching for key-names, regex searches, and can better handle DOM nodes

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` using `window` and the latest version of Canary.

Answer (score 5):

This should work. It uses recursion to achieve the result.

```
function globalSearch(obj, value) {
    for(var p in obj)
        if(obj[p] == value){
            return(p);
        }else if(typeof obj[p] == "object" && obj[p] != obj){
           var te = globalSearch(obj[p], value);
           if(te!=false){ return p + "." + te }
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Doing it for window: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.valueOf (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 0):

Make your solution recursive. If you have an object, call your function again.

```
function globalSearch(obj, value) {
    for(var p in obj) {
        if (obj[p] == value) {
            return(p);
        } else if (typeof obj[p] === "object") {
            var recursiveCheck= globalSearch(obj[p], value);
            if (recursiveCheck) {
                return p + "." + recursiveCheck;
            }
        }
    }
}
globalSearch(window, 'StackOverflow');
```

I bet most browsers will hit a warning for too much looping.

Comment: Notice that your funtion get stuck using `window` as your `obj`.

Comment: @Ravan: check out my answer, which accounts for that.

Answer (score 0):

This code, based on the other answer, allows for all possible value matches to be found.

```
function globalSearch(startObject, value, returnFirstResult = false) {
    var stack = [[startObject,'']];
    var searched = [];
    var found = new Set();

    var isArray = function(test) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call( test ) === '[object Array]';
    }

    while(stack.length) {
        var fromStack = stack.pop();
        var obj = fromStack[0];
        var address = fromStack[1];

        if( typeof obj == typeof value && obj == value) {
            if (returnFirstResult) {
                return address == '' ? false : address;
            }
            found.add(address)
        }if(typeof obj == "object" && searched.indexOf(obj) == -1){
           if ( isArray(obj) ) {
                var prefix = '[';
                var postfix = ']';
           }else {
                var prefix = '.';
                var postfix = '';
           }
           for( i in obj ) {
                stack.push( [ obj[i], address + prefix + i + postfix ] );
           }
           searched.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return Array.from(found);
}
```