# Find which variable holds a value using Chrome Devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to access some values in a remote web application to build a Chrome extension.

For that, I'd like to find which JS variable holds a given value, and I was wondering if one can do some sort of "global search" on the values of all variables in memory.

Is this possible with any tool? Inspector, profiler, etc...?

Comment: Wait... I have the same interest right now. but aren't the two answers a bit off to the problem op's asking? you're trying to search/scan literally "all" variables/objects in the js source files, not just global/window variables but including out-of-scope variables, correct? if I could dump or something all data from profiling in the "memory" or "performance" tab, I guess. so did you find a hint on the issue, op?

Answer (score 9):

All credit for [this answer goes to tomwrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12103127/2620045).  See his answer for more details on the issues/improvements for this snippet.

**The code**

```
function globalSearch(startObject, value) {
    var stack = [[startObject,'']];
    var searched = [];
    var found = false;

    var isArray = function(test) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call( test ) === '[object Array]';
    }

    while(stack.length) {
        var fromStack = stack.pop();
        var obj = fromStack[0];
        var address = fromStack[1];

        if( typeof obj == typeof value && obj == value) {
            var found = address;
            break;
        }else if(typeof obj == "object" && searched.indexOf(obj) == -1){
           if ( isArray(obj) ) {
              var prefix = '[';
              var postfix = ']';
           }else {
              var prefix = '.';
              var postfix = '';
           }
           for( i in obj ) {
              stack.push( [ obj[i], address + prefix + i + postfix ] );
           }
           searched.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return found == '' ? true : found;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate over all items in the global scope like this:

```
var test = 123,
    someVar = 812;

for(key in window){
    if(typeof window[key] === 'number' && window[key] == 123){
        console.log(key, window[key]);
    }
}
```

Combine that with some recursion, and you could theoretically iterate over all objects and their children, available in a object:

```
function searchObject(object, search){
    for(key in object){
        if(typeof object[key] === 'number' || typeof object[key] === 'string'){
            if(object[key] === search){
                console.log(key, window[key]);
            }
        }else if(typeof object[key] === 'object'){
            searchObject(object[key], search);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a ***quick and dirty*** example. It only checks for strict equality (So no *"string contains"*), and it iterates over arrays with `for in`, which is evil. But it should give you an idea of how it works.

Don't pass `window` or `document` to this function, though. That won't work due to circular references.

---

However, you can also place a [breakpoint in your code in the chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints).
You can then inspect the current value of your variables in the "Scope Variables" area on the right.

Comment: why not do `window[key] === 123` instead of comparing types manually and then using coercing equality?

Comment: @JanDvorak: It was throwing errors for me if I didn't: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value ` (Chrome console)

Comment: This can fail easily: security exceptions thrown when touching cross-origin frames, cyclic structures (in fact, there are a few already)...

Comment: "Don't pass window or document to this function, though" - or any DOM node (except maybe detached nodes without children) or ...

Comment: ... or anything that JSON.stringify would refuse

Comment: That's precisely what I'm trying to do: inspect all global variables, like the ones `window` might contain.