# Find string in temporary Javascript variable and get it's name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I'm trying to debug a very large obfuscated Javascript code.
I need to find a string in temporary variable and get the name of that var.
Is it possible to search for string in values of all variables in debugging mode with Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Does the search need to be recursive? And does it need to only search strings?

Comment: I'm searching certain string, so I need to search for vars of type string. I'm not sure about "search need to be recursive"

Comment: What if you have `window["location"]["href"] = "yourRequiredString";` and you searched through the `window` object. Does it still need to be able to find `href`, even though it's on a property of `location` and not `window`?

Comment: Yes, I need to research every single var in memory where string could be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursively search for a value in global variables and its properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102425/recursively-search-for-a-value-in-global-variables-and-its-properties)

Comment: I need to do this research in debugging mode, this var not exist after script finish its execution.

Comment: You can run JS at any point, just put a breakpoint and a watch in