# Hook function without direct reference

Tags: javascript, hook

I try at the moment to hook a Javascript function in a WebGame.
The problem is that this function isn't available in the global DOM. The only way that I get it working, is to set a breakpoint in the browser debugger, override the function in the console and let it run again. Unfortunately the whole JS-Code is Obfuscated and loaded via a webpack lib.

My question is now, is there any way to find that function from outside or to automate the "breakpoint way"? I want to load my hook without to set manual a  breakpoint.

I tried to find the function with that: [Recursively search for a value in global variables and its properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102425/recursively-search-for-a-value-in-global-variables-and-its-properties) but without success.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to use greasemonkey and a simple python flask server.
The greasemonkey script prevent that the js file get load, instead its load the script from the flask server, that download the js and modify it.