# Access third party React app state from outside React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A website uses a third-party plugin that comes with a React application.

I need to get a JS function that reads some values from that React app state. However, I cannot find the React instance in the global `window` scope... Where does React store the app instance?

My attempt: When I install the browser extension "**React Developer Tools**" in Chrome, then there is a global object **`window.$r`** that allows me to access the React state. I can do `var title = window.$r.state.title`.
However, the `$r` object is only present when the React Developer Tools are installed. I need to write some JS that works for all users, even when they do not have that browser extension.

Also, I cannot modify the React app to make the state available via a ref or export. I can only write JS outside the app.

I have also tried to examine the root DOM node that renders the main application Component but I have not found a way to read application details from that...

Comment: Who said there's only ever a single React application running on a page? I've written plenty of pages that use 10 or more React "applications" for the various parts of a larger not-React-managed interface.

Comment: That's good feedback, Mike! Do you have any suggestions on how I can access a specific application (e.g. when I know the root DOM node)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution by searching through a ton of JS data, but I could extract a function that returns the state object of the React application.

I noticed that the state is nested like 6 - 10 levels below the actual react root DOM node, so I wrote a function that loops through the React app and identifies the state by an attribute name.

This code is tested with React 16.7

```
function getAppState(rootNode, globalAttributeName) {
    var $root = jQuery(rootNode);
    var reactState = false;
    var searchStack = [];
    var searched = [];

    // Fetch the "__reactInternalInstance$..." attribute from the DOM node.
    for ( const key in $root[0] ) {
        // The full name changes on every page load, e.g. "__reactInternalInstance$ek3wnas4g6"
        if (0 === key.indexOf('__reactInternalInstance$') ) {
            searchStack.push($root[0][key]);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Find the state by examining the object structure.
    while (searchStack.length) {
        var obj = searchStack.pop();

        if (obj && typeof obj == 'object' && -1 === searched.indexOf(obj)) {
            if ( undefined !== obj[ globalAttributeName ] ) {
                reactState = obj;
                break;
            }

            for (i in obj) {
                searchStack.push(obj[i]);
            }
            searched.push(obj);
        }
    }

    return reactState;
}

// In my example, I know that the app uses "state.activeModule", 
// so I search for the key "activeModule" to identify the state:
getAppState('#root-id', 'activeModule');

// Here is the full path to the state, in my example:
// __reactInternalInstance$ek3wnas4g6g.alternate.return.alternate.return.alternate.memoizedProps._owner.alternate.memoizedState
```

This answer did greatly help me to find this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12103127/313501