# Using setState without React Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have `$r` available when React Dev Tool extension is installed. Is it possible to have something like that without using React Dev Tool?

e.g.

With `$r` this works:

```js
$r.setState((state) => {
    return {username: "blabla"}
})
```

I need to do something like that but without the react dev tools.

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate someone else's react app?

Comment: @CharlesBamford  No. In short I need to run automated tests using Headless browser that change the state of the react app by manipulating different attributes of a form component. However I cannot install React Dev tools on the headless browser.

Comment: What testing framework are you using?  It seems like perhaps you are approaching this from the incorrect angle...

Comment: There are a ton of existing react testing frameworks. Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, research existing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to do it finally myself with help from [Access third party React app state from outside React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60252820/access-third-party-react-app-state-from-outside-react)

Modified code from that answer here to change the state as well:

```js
function setAppState(rootNode, globalAttributeName, newValue) {
    var $root = $(rootNode)._reactRootContainer;
    var reactState = false;
    var searchStack = [];
    var searched = [];

    // Fetch the "_internalRoot" attribute from the DOM node.
    for ( const key in $root ) {
        if (0 === key.indexOf('_internalRoot') ) {
            searchStack.push($root[key]);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Find the state by examining the object structure.
    while (searchStack.length) {
        var obj = searchStack.pop();

        if (obj && typeof obj == 'object' && -1 === searched.indexOf(obj)) {
            if ( undefined !== obj[ globalAttributeName ] ) {
                reactState = obj;
                break;
            }

            for (i in obj) {
                searchStack.push(obj[i]);
            }
            searched.push(obj);
        }
    }

    // Take the last pushed object as it contains the State to be changed
    state = searched[searched.length - 1].memoizedState;
    state[globalAttributeName] = newValue;

    return state;

}
```

`rootNode` will be the id of the root element of react app e.g. `#app`

`globalAttributeName` will be the Key that you need to change

`newValue` will be the new state of that key